# How are Drupal Blocks ordered?

Tags: drupal

I know they are weighed through the interface found at admin/build/block (and through the weight field in users table) but beyond that, is there any ordering used on blocks of same weight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Block sorted by region, weight, then module name. No title. It then follows the insert order on blocks table. See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.module/function/block_list/6

Comment: found it: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.module/function/block_list/6 thanks for your answer :)